# Is it possible to combine address bar and search bar of opera mobile into one

Tags: opera-browser

I had been using stock browser all the while. Recently, I found out that opera mobile is much more faster when I double tap to zoom in. I would like to switch my daily use to opera mobile. However, the shortcoming I found out is that, they do not have a single bar for me to search and type address. Is there any workaround or plugin for me to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any way to physically combine the two fields. However, the most recent update (11.1) added the following:

> **One field does it all**
>
> You can now type both web addresses
>   and search queries in your browser's
>   address field. Or, if you prefer, you
>   can still use the search field with
>   your favorite search engines.

So if you start typing into the address bar, you'll now be given the option to perform a search for whatever you entered. You just tap on the "Search: [text]" item that appears under the address bar:

[image: Example of Opera search]